# Why does querying Firebase realtime db require listener?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am new to firebase and noSQL databases. I've read the docs and watched instructional videos but there is one concept I haven't fully grasped.

Why is it that querying the database requires a listener such as .on("value")?

Since these listeners are triggered whenever there is a change of sorts (nodes created, edited, children created) shouldn't there be a more direct way of getting the data from the db? Such as

```
ref.orderBy("age"). equalTo(30).get()
```

A method to just get what's in there at the time he instruction is executed, without having to listen to some sort of event?

In SQL it's not like you have to wait for something to change in your db to make this query work:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE X == Y
```

PS: I know .once() also exists, but my question is more about: if my db never changed, how would I be able to query it and always get the same query result/snapshot?

Comment: If you know that once() exists, why aren't you using it?  That's exactly what you want if you don't need to attach a listener.

Comment: *Why is it that querying the database requires a listener such as .on("value")?* - it doesn't require a listener. That would only be the case when you want to know about data that changes that matches your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define a platform so I will use this Swift pseudo-code example. Suppose we want to get a list of all users, one time.

```
let usersRef = my_firebase.child("users")
usersRef.observeSingleEvent(by: .value, with: { snapshot in
    //all users are returned to the app in the snapshot
    //   .value means 'give me everything in the specified node'
    // so then we can iterate over the snapshot to get each users data
}
```

You can call the above code any time to get the list of users and it does not add an observer (listener) to the node. It's a one-shot.

Whereas, if we want to be notified of users that are *added*

```
let usersRef = my_firebase.child("users")
usersRef.observe(by: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    //upon first calling this, each user will be sent to the app in the snapshot
    //  and after that, any user that's added
}
```

The above code attaches an observer (listener) to the users node and whenever a user is added, it's provided to the app via the snapshot.

Note the use of .observeSingleEvent vs .observe and .value to get everything in the node vs .childAdded to get a specific node.

Comment: Thank you Jay! I'm using node.js so I guess my equivalent is .once()